# making primeFaces ajax call in dataTable

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, primefaces

I am using JSF 2 with PrimeFaces 2.2. I tried making an ajax call through a select box onchange event in a dataTable. I was able to see the System.outs printing but, I could not see the components given in the **update** attribute getting updated.  I have given the dataTableId in the **update** attribute.

I guess the problem now is the selectbox is getting populated again and an ajax call is made.  Should we give only the parent tags in the **update** attirbute, for the ajax call to work. Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the ID in the `update` attribute does not start with `:`, it becomes relative to the ID of the current component inside the same [`NamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component. But since the `h:dataTable` **is** an `NamingContainer` component, you need to reference it by an absolute ID. Rightclick the JSF page in the webbrowser and choose *View Source* to see the generated HTML DOM tree. Locate the HTML `<table>` element which is generated by the `<h:dataTable>`, determine the value of its `id` attribute and use exactly that id in the `update` attribute, prefixed with `:`.

Comment: Hi BalusC 
       I have specified it in the ajax call like this <p:ajax update=":table1"  event="change"> and this is showing me the following in the log 
   Component ":table1" not found to be updated partially

Comment: I said, the `id` in the generated HTML source, not in the JSF source. JavaScript/Ajax operates in webbrowser on HTML, not in webserver on JSF. Open the page in **webbrowser** (not in Java/JSF editor), rightclick it and do *View Source* to see the **HTML DOM tree** (not the JSF component tree). It should look like `formId:tableId` where `formId` is the ID of the `<h:form>`. You should then use `:formId:tableId` in the `update` attribute.

Comment: Thank you BalusC

    Is there any way that I could get the count of the dataTable row ?

..... I am getting the id in the source like this ..... table1:0:receiptCode ...... even if I give it as table1:receiptCode .... the component is not getting rendered, so asking you if I could get the row number